# Passing PHP variable to html so it can be sent to another PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get variables from a PHP file to HTML so I can add more variables when sending it to another PHP file. this is my first time trying something like this so I'm at a lost

the idea is to take this variable which is coming from HTML1 to PHP1

```
$Username = $_POST["Username"];
```

and then put it into HTML2 so it can be put into this bigger set of variables in PHP2

```
$SCode = $_POST["Username"];
$Equipment = $_GET["Equipment"];
$TimeS = $_GET["TimeS"];
$TimeE = $_GET["TimeE"];
```

i tried using header to bypass the html and do a PHP to PHP but with out the variable coming from the first HTML it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as a string (JSON) in HTML [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```php
<div data-equipment='<?php echo json_encode($equipment); ?>'></div>
```

or if you would like to use it only in PHP you can use [session variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```php
$_SESSION["someSession"] = $equipment;
```

Comment: Since JSON uses `"` around keys and values, echo it inside a HTML attribute that also uses `"` will generate invalid HTML. Something like: `data-equipment="["foo"]"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three way to do this :

**SESSION**

```
 $_SESSION["variable_name"] = $equipment;
```

**COOKIE**

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

**USING INPUT**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $equipment; ?>" name="input_name">
```

the hidden input will not show at the browser level and hold the value.